# What are the dimensions of US outlet holes?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, socket, cord-and-plug

I am specifically referring to the standard NEMA 5-15 three hole outlet that is used in North America. What are the dimensions of the holes in the outlets?

Surprisingly, I am having difficulty in finding this information on line.

Comment: I just measured a plug the neutral was .248" the hot was .246", both were .060 thick so the outlet would be slightly longer and wider. the ground was .192 x .187.

Answer (score 22):

Let me introduce you to the wonderful world of Google Image search:

[nema 5-15 dimensions](https://www.google.com/search?q=nema+5-15+dimensions&biw=1810&bih=1017&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

It's a great way to find drawings and other visual information.

Here's a drawing pulled from the search results:

[image]

[Powercord CN](http://www.powercordcn.com/NEMA-5-15P-Power-Cords.html)

Dimiensions are millimeters with a comma used instead of a decimal point.

**NEMA Website**

Following some image searches and regular searches I also came across the official [NEMA Website](https://www.nema.org/Standards/Pages/Wiring-Devices-Dimensional-Specifications.aspx)

This [NEMA WD 6 - Non-Locking Plugs and Receptacles - Excerpt](https://www.nema.org/Standards/ComplimentaryDocuments/NEMA%20WD%206%20-%20Non-Locking%20Plugs%20and%20Receptacles%20-%20Excerpt.pdf) PDF should have the information you want.

Comment: The first image does not take into account the difference in size between the "hot" and "neutral" holes. But the pdf attachment is detailed in that respect. Thank you!

Comment: You're right.  I think the included image must be for one manufacturer's plug and they decided to just use to same-sized prongs.

Comment: @BenA Three-prong plugs do not need to have polarized hot-neutral connections, as the third grounding pin provides that polarization.